# Get Word.Application object from AccessibleObjectFromWindow in C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I am trying to get Word, Access, Excel, and Powerpoint application objects from the window handles of their open windows. The code below worked fine to return an Access.Application object, but it fails for Word. It always returns a null `app` value in the fourth parameter (ppvObject). I don't know why.

The only difference that I know of is that Access uses one process per Access window while Word uses one process for N Word windows.

Maybe the Idispatch has to be different for Access/Excel/whatever that I'm looking for? I searched the net (and relevant posts here on SO) to find an answer, but could not find an answer or example. I saw one code snippet where the guy built up his own long GUID using class values and versions and such things.

Why does my code fail? If I need a different GUID Idispatch expression, how can find information on which one to use (or build) for different applications such as Word or my own custom applications? Thank you.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

  [DllImport("oleacc.dll")]
  internal static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(
    IntPtr hwnd, uint id, ref Guid iid,
    [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)]
    ref object ppvObject);

  /// <summary>
  /// Return the Word.Application object associated with the input
  /// raw window handle of an open Word window. Return null if the
  /// call fails. 
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="hwnd">Valid rawptr to an open Word window.</param>
  /// <returns>The Word application object in the window.</returns>
  public static Word.Application
    AppWordFromWindowHandle(IntPtr hwnd) {
    const uint objidNativeom = 0xFFFFFFF0;
    Guid idispatch = new Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
    object app = null;
    var hr = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd, objidNativeom, ref idispatch, ref app);
    if (hr != 0 && app == null) {
      var msg = $"Getting Word object failed. App ptr is null";
      Hsdll.Logger.LogSend(msg, true);
      return null;
    }

    return (Word.Application) app;
  }

Here is an example of someone building up a GUID from app/version info.
I could not find any documentation on how to do this, or if I *should*
do it for something as common as Microsoft Office apps.

    //'Defines the IDispatch variable. The interface _
    // ID is {90140000-0016-0409-0000-0000000FF1CE}.
    //'NOT USING {00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}, _
    // which could be a problem (for the guy who did this; not me)

    //'9 is release version - first version shipped (initial release)
    //'0 is release type - retail/oem
    //'14 is major version
    //'0000 is minor version
    //'0016 is product ID - MS Excel 2010
    //'0409 is language identifier - English
    //'0 is x86 or x64 - this is x86
    //'000 reserved
    //'0 is debug/ship
    //'000000FF1CE is office family ID
```

Comment: What's the `HRESULT` returned from `AccessibleObjectFromWindow`?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time and interest. The code is -2147467259. And as I type that, I remember seeing this same code (starting with -214...) somewhere in my searches. Hex=80004005x.

Comment: `0x80004005` is the generic `E_FAIL` error code, that translates to *"something went wrong"*. Not entirely insightful. But since you are requesting [OBJ_NATIVEOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/object-identifiers) *"third-party applications can return **any** COM interface"*. Maybe try to request an `IUnknown` interface instead.

Comment: Thank you for the `IUnknown` idea and the link to a list of OBJID types. Unfortunately, `IUnkown` is not in the interface list and my searches on the net for that kind of interface failed to produce anything that looked plausible. How can I request an `IUnkown` interface, exactly? All other OBJID types are supposed to inherit from it, but it's a puzzle why Access would work and Word would fail. I will try Powerpoint and excel to see if they fail the same way while I wait for your next response. Thank you again.

Comment: @IInspectable, The OBJID_NATIVEOM works fine with Access and fails for Word, PowerPoint, Outlook, and Excel. Maybe the object model is not available via the process/windowhandle method for those apps, by design?